# SQL query to Remove Duplicate data of specific type from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am given following table:

```
col1|col2  
Hyd |Bag  
kol |Chi  
Del |Pat  
Bag |Hyd
```

I need to keep this

```
Kol |Chi  
Del |Pat
```

and
I need to keep either of the given row i.e:

```
Hyd |Bag  
Bag |Hyd
```

I tried with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_kafee a WHERE  (SELECT count(*) FROM test_kafee b 
WHERE a.Temp1 = b.temp2 AND a.temp2 = b.Temp1 ) = 0
```

which give unique one, but for duplicate I am not able to stop one with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test_kafee3 a WHERE  (SELECT count(*) FROM test_kafee b 
WHERE a.Temp1 = b.temp2 AND a.temp2 = b.Temp1 ) > 0
```

Table may contain more then one duplicate, like this:
col1|col2
Hyd |Bag
kol |Chi
Del |Pat
Bag |Hyd
Chi |kol

Comment: Could you create a http://sqlfiddle.com? Also, what is your database?

Comment: i am using Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

You want all unique *combinations* in your table.

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1
WHERE col1 <= col2
UNION
SELECT col2, col1 FROM table1
WHERE col2 < col1
```

`UNION` will remove duplicates for you.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the required rows into a Temp table

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
SELECT col1,col2
FROM YOURTABLE
MINUS
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT col1,col2
  FROM YOURTABLE
  INTERSECT
  SELECT col2,col1
  FROM YOURTABLE;
)
```

Truncate your actual table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE YOURTABLE;
```

Insert back the records from your temp table

```
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server (next time, please add a tag with the database so that we wouldn't have to guess) you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl table (col1 char(3), col2 char(3))

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'Hyd', 'Bag'
UNION 
SELECT 'kol', 'Chi'
UNION 
SELECT 'Del', 'Pat'
UNION 
SELECT 'Bag', 'Hyd'

SELECT DISTINCT T1.Col1, T1.Col2
FROM @tbl T1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2
    FROM @tbl T1 INNER JOIN @tbl T2 ON(T1.Col1 = T2.Col2 AND T1.Col2 = T2.col1)
    ) T2 ON(T1.col1 = T2.col1 AND T1.col2 = T2.col2)
WHERE T2.col1 IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 1 T1.Col1, T1.Col2
FROM @tbl T1 INNER JOIN 
@tbl T2 ON(T1.Col1 = T2.Col2 AND T1.Col2 = T2.col1)
```

Comment: There can be more then one such type of duplicate, for that case this query will not work

Comment: You are correct. I failed to notice that until reading your comment. thank you.